# Connection getting reset but execution still happening in background in PHP?

Tags: php, hosting, web-hosting

I have just changed my host, and everything is now running smoothly, with only one glitch.

I have a page (precisely.me/fpl/epl), which gives the user the option to refresh the score. This is basically a link to precisely.me/fpl/eplrefresh which fetches data from another site, updates the table, and then redirects it back to precisely.me/fpl/epl.

The thing is that I'm getting this error on Chrome - The webpage at http://precisely.me/fpl/eplrefresh might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address
and something similar on Firefox - The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

I tried to set max_execution_time = 300 in php.ini but that didn't work. Do note that despite this error, the script is running successfully in the background, and the scores do get updated. But before it can redirect the user, I get the error.

What should I be changing in php.ini to make it work?

This really shouldn't be needed as it works on localhost and my previous server. But anyways snippet of eplrefresh.php

```
<?php   
$dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','fplscore') or die("can't connect");
$team_epl=array("Arsenal","Aston Villa", "Chelsea","Everton"); //Trimmed for now

$teamid_epl=array("24854","17","109276","57");

$playernames_epl=array("Jackoff", "Epic Fail", "ENR", "Beric");


set_time_limit(500); //Minimum time for page to expire
$i=0;
foreach ($teamid_epl as $x)
{$team_name=$team_epl[$i];  

$thisgw = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($dbc,"select gwno from gameweek"));
$gw=$thisgw['gwno'];
$str2="http://fantasy.premierleague.com/entry/".$x."/event-history/".$gw; 
    $file=fopen($str2,"r") or die("Heavy load on FPL. Please try later");
    while(!feof($file))
            {$str=fgets($file);

            if(preg_match('/(<div class="ismSBValue ismSBPrimary">(.*))/', $str,$ar)) 
                {   $str2=fgets($file);
                    $str2=fgets($file); 
                    $str2 = strip_tags($str2);
                    $str2=str_replace("pts","",$str2);
                    $temp1=(int)$str2;

                }

            if(preg_match('/(<dl class="ismDefList ismSBDefList">(.*))/', $str,$ar)) 
                    {           .....
                                                    $str2=fgets($file);
                            $str2 = strip_tags($str2);
                            $str2=str_replace("pts","",$str2);
                            $str2=str_replace("(-","",$str2);
                            $str2=str_replace(")","",$str2);
                            $temp2=(int)$str2;  
                            $z=$temp1-$temp2;
$gw=$gw-19;         
                            $gw="gw".$gw;
                            $q="update epl_score set ".$gw."=$z  where team='$team_name'" ;
                            $result=mysqli_query($dbc,$q) or die("unable to execute query");

                    }


            }
$i++;
}   
header("Location: epl");        
?>
```

Comment: Please post the code of `eplrefresh`.

Comment: There is no way the problem can be with eplrefresh....It works both on localhost, and on my previous server. Has to be with a configuration file? Do you still want the code

Comment: I think it could still be helpful yes.

Answer (score 0):

The construction click -> update from remote server -> redirect is not a very good one. With more then a few users you will get into serious problems because you will run out of workers.

Why not set up a cronjob to get the latest scores, save them somewhere and pull updates scores with ajax. Much less overhead (or even better, push them !).

We will need to see your code to know what is wrong with it.

Ps, my money is on a timeout/error somewhere between the apache server and the php backend. This probably is not something that you can fix.

You posted your code now .....  try adding exit(); after the header and dont close your php code (it could send newlines and you dont want that when redirecting)

Answer (score 0):

I've just restructured your code a little bit for performance improvement.
The most important thing I made is removing `$thisgw = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($dbc,"select gwno from gameweek"));` from the foreach because it is always the same.

Other than that how many times is your `update` query executed per team? This should be exactly 1 time. Therefore I would try to remove this part from the `while` of the file reader.

```
<?php   
$dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','fplscore') or die("can't connect");

$epl_arr = array(
    array('id' => 24854, 'team' => 'Arsenal', 'player' => 'Jackoff'),
    array('id' => 17, 'team' => 'Aston Villa', 'player' => 'Epic Fail'),
    array('id' => 109276, 'team' => 'Chelsea', 'player' => 'ENR'),
    array('id' => 57, 'team' => 'Everton', 'player' => 'Beric'),
);

$thisgw = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($dbc,"select gwno from gameweek"));

foreach ($epl_arr as $ea)
{
    $gw = $thisgw['gwno'];
    $team_name = $ea['team']; 
    $team_id = $ea['id']; 
    $player_name = $ea['player']; 

    $str2="http://fantasy.premierleague.com/entry/".$team_id."/event-history/".$gw; 
    $file=fopen($str2,"r") or die("Heavy load on FPL. Please try later");

    while(!feof($file))
    {
        $str=fgets($file);

        if(preg_match('/(<div class="ismSBValue ismSBPrimary">(.*))/', $str,$ar)) 
        {   
            $str2 = fgets($file);
            $str2 = fgets($file);
            $str2 = strip_tags($str2);
            $str2 = str_replace("pts","",$str2);
            $temp1 = $str2;

        }

        if(preg_match('/(<dl class="ismDefList ismSBDefList">(.*))/', $str,$ar)) 
        {
                $str2 = fgets($file);
                $str2 = strip_tags($str2);
                $str2 = str_replace("pts","",$str2);
                $str2 = str_replace("(-","",$str2);
                $str2 = str_replace(")","",$str2);
                $temp2 = $str2;  
                $z = $temp1-$temp2;
                $gw = $gw-19;         
                $gw = "gw".$gw;
                $q = "update epl_score set ".$gw."=$z  where team='$team_name'" ;
                $result=mysqli_query($dbc,$q) or die("unable to execute query");
        }
    }
}   

header("Location: epl");        
?>
```

If this doesn't help, also have a look at [`memory_limit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).

Maybe you can also remove your `header` at the end of the file for testing purpose. There might be a problem with output before it.

Also try debugging with setting [`ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.error-reporting.php)